# Why is this code not producing desired result?

Tags: java, for-loop, concatenation

The following java problem question is from http://codingbat.com/prob/p132118 :

Given two strings, append them together (known as "concatenation") and return the result. However, if the concatenation creates a double-char, then omit one of the chars, so "abc" and "cat" yields "abcat". i.e:

```
conCat("abc", "cat") → "abcat"
conCat("dog", "cat") → "dogcat"
conCat("abc", "") → "abc"
```

This is the solution I worked out:

```
public String conCat(String a, String b) {

String result = a + b; 
String r = "";
String f = "";

for(int i= 0; i < result.length(); i++)
 {  
   f   = Character.toString(result.charAt(i));      
   if(!( f.equals(result.charAt(i))) )
   r += f;             
 }

 return r;
 }
```

My question is- where is the logic flaw that causes my code to concatenate "ab" + "bc" to "abbc" instead of "abc"?

Comment: Why are you casting f to String and then comparing it to char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the result of `a + b` because you are comparing a string, `f`, to a char, `result.charAt(i)`. They are never equal because they are of different types, so `r += f;` is executed unconditionally.

Even if you corrected this problem, your approach would not work since you have already concatenated the strings: you can't tell the difference between concatenating e.g. `conCat("ab", "bc")` vs `conCat("abbc", "")`. You need to do something *before* you actually concatenate the strings.

---

You need to drop a character if all of the following are true:

1. `a` is non-empty
2. `b` is non-empty
3. The last character of `a` is equal to the first character of `b`.

In that case, just chop off the first character of `b` before concatenating. Otherwise, just concatenate the strings as they are.

```
public String conCat(String a, String b) {
 if (!a.isEmpty() && !b.isEmpty() && a.charAt(a.length() - 1) == b.charAt(0)) {
    return a + b.substring(1);
  } else {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

Comment: TS asked a question about their code. It's not fun at all to just solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: thank you very much, this produces the desired result, but I want to know why my code logic is not working.